# Subscribing MediaCapture RecordLimitationExceeded for recording audio (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Do we have to subscribe MediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded event if we're only recording audio (no camera/webcam) on a Windows Phone 8.1 RT app? I checked the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.recordlimitationexceeded) and it looks like this is valid for capturing videos.

Can we record audio safely without handling this event?

Comment: Have you tried recording just audio for > three hours?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I'm handling it, but I wanted to check if it needs to be handled.

Comment: I would handle it anytime I'm using the MediaCapture. I don't see anything in the documentation about the event being video-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Since Audio/Video etc are just modes for the MediaCapture class and the RecordLimitationExceeded event is purely memory state event that looks after the media capture instance. You can simply go ahead with whatever you want.

One can use video capture without handling the event too. summarizing, it is optional.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. It's only true if you never expect your users to record for longer than 3 hours, or if you never expect them to run out of disk space. But then, you don't know if the record limitation will change in the future.